# live stream using python showing very slow frame rate on browser

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I am setting flask server to stream live from camera on web site. i have  used code from github link in following 
https://github.com/log0/video_streaming_with_flask_example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can simply reduce size of each frame as follow

```
newimg = cv2.resize(oriimg,(int(newX),int(newY)))
```

if you are using low end machine